# Voltage flow to charge a battery

Tags: battery-charging

A windmill creates a voltage, to charge a battery do you connect the positive of the windmill to the positive of the battery, or the negative? Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks too much like a homework problem with no effort that could be solved with a simple google search.

Answer (score 4):

You connect the positive to the positive.

As you know, under normal operations the battery supplies current from the positive terminal as the chemical reaction continues within the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff2YV8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you want to charge a battery, you need to put current back into the positive terminal to reverse the chemical reaction.

As such you need to force a voltage to the positive terminal that is greater than the open circuit voltage of the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVDxYW.png)</sup>

Comment: You might consider saying "force a voltage" rather than "attach a voltage", and you might consider saying "open circuit voltage" rather than "output voltage".